# How can I map database 'code' values into full strings using ASP.NET MVC4 C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, data-binding, data-annotations

I've got a external database (reading rights only) with fields containing codes representing stringdata. Unfortunatetly, the codes and explanations are not digitalized. Instead, I've got a bunch of papers stating T=Toyota, M=Mercedes, F=Ferrari, etc..

I'm looking for a way to convert these **codes into full strings** and keep things maintainable.

```
[Desired result]              [Current result]
 -Regnumber   -Brand          -Regnumber    -Brand
 ABC001        Toyota          ABC001        T
 FGH783        Ferrari         FGH783        F
 LKJ345        Mercedes        LKJ345M       M
```

I considered using enums, but that seems like a lot of work declaring (500+ values) so I was thinking using resource files (XML should be easy to maintain) but **I'm open for suggestions**.

My plan was to create a seperate resource file for every table containing codes:

```
./Resources/Cars/BRAND.resx
./Resources/House/BUILDINGTYPE.resx
./Resources/House/COLOR.resx
./Resources/Flowers/NAME.resx
```

That way, it would be easy to locate and change the content in the future. But I would like to know what would be a good place (Model, View, other) to receive the values from the resource file?

Furthermore, I tried to use [DataAnnotations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.aspx) but **I'm probably missing the point completely**. I was under the impression that one could pass a database value to a resource file just by adding a data annotation of display type "ResourceType = foo" but then I get the following error:

Cannot retrieve property 'Name' because localization failed.  Type 'MyProject.Resources.Car.BRAND' is not public or does not contain a public static string property with the name 'registration number'

It seems like the resource file is using the display name instead of the field value retrieved from the database (the access modifier IS set to public)

---

Model

```
    // ...

    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="registration number")]
    public string registrationNr { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="Brand", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Car.BRAND))]
    public string BrandCode { get; set; }

    //...
```

---

View

```
foreach(modelItem in Model.Car)
{
    //...

    @Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.BrandCode)
    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => modelItem.BrandCode)

    //...
}
```

---

However, the solution of my problem doesn't have to use resource files, as long as I can map codes to values and maintain them I'd be a happy man. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've answered your own question.

`Unfortunatetly, the codes and explanations are not digitalized` - you need to put them in your DB and just do the join when querying.

UPDATE:

Other solution would be to create a static `Dictionary<string, string>` with the mappings and do the lookup while populating the model. You could reuse `BrandCode` property or define a new one.

Comment: That is a good solution, though I would have to create my own database in that case. I only have reading rights on the original (external) database. Hopefully someone can shine a light on other solutions too.